# twocolumn span across multiple pages

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, two-column

I want to prevent twocolumn from using magazine-style section breaks across multicolumn pages. I'm currently invoking twocolumn like so:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
```

But this is creating the following layout in the document:

```
Page 1: A B
Page 1: A C
Page 2: C D
Page 2: D E
```

The letters illustrate a single section. I would much rather prefer:

```
Page 1: A B
Page 1: A C
Page 2: D C
Page 2: D E
```

So ideally, it should go something like this: `'If this is a section to be continued on the next page, continue it in the same column on the next page, otherwise put it in the left column'.`

Comment: This is really confusing, at least for a left-to-right language. How does the reader know when to switch to the first column again?

Comment: There are packages for two making two separate flows one in each column, often used for multi-language texts with one language in column 1 and another in column 2 (eg parallel or paracol) however there you know in advance which column text is aimed at. Switching automatically would be very confusing, also the algorithm is underspecified above what if section A continues for several pages, all col 1. Is col 2 blank, or is latex supposed to (somehow?) look ahead and collect text from later in the document to fill column 2?

Answer (score 2):

There are packages for making two separate flows one in each column, often used for multi-language texts with one language in column 1 and another in column 2 (eg `parallel` or `paracol`) however there you know in advance which column text is aimed at. Switching automatically would be very confusing, also the algorithm is underspecified above: what if section A continues for several pages, all col 1. Is col 2 blank, or is latex supposed to (somehow?) look ahead and collect text from later in the document to fill column 2?